# FluentValidation always return generic error message

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I am using **FluentValidation** and I have the following validation rule:

```
      RuleFor(x => x.ClassId)
            .NotNull()
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .WithMessage("Class is required field");
```

but when ClassId is null it shows its generic error message:

> 'Class Id' must not be empty

How to show the error message I specified inside the WithMessage() method?

Comment: What happend if you get rid of the condition `GreaterThan(0)` does that ended up with the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on Md Farid Uddin Kiron's comment I think for every rule we need to add WithMessage() as followings:

```
      RuleFor(x => x.ClassId)
        .NotNull()
        .WithMessage("Class is required field")
        .GreaterThan(0)
        .WithMessage("Class is required field");
```

Comment: Yes, I did the test without `GreaterThan(0)` which works as expected. So Yes each time need to overrriede the message.